# How to remove a character from a word but only if it is at the beginning or the end?

Tags: python

```
def data_from_file(filename):

    list1 = []

    infile = open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8")

    lines = infile.read().split()
    lines = " ".join(lines)
    lines1 = lines.replace("." , "")
    lines2 = lines1.replace(",", "")
    lines3 = lines2.replace("\n", "")
    lines4 = lines3.replace("\"", "")
    lines5 = lines4.replace("\\", "")
    lines6 = lines5.replace("\"", "")
    lines7 = lines6.replace(":", "")
    lines8 = lines7.replace(";", "")

    lines9 = lines8.split()

    for i in lines9:
        if i.isalpha():
            list1.append(i)
    return list1
```

Hi code newbie here,

Basically what I need to do is read  data from a certain file. I then need to remove the characters such as (" ; : . , \n ' )  but only if they are at the start or end of the word. Currently my program removes every instance of these characters. For example I want to be able to turn "cars" into cars but ca"rs would stay as ca"rs

The next part of the program involves only selecting the words which have an alphanumeric character in every position.This part works perfectly.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any work with regular expressions? This is a perfect use-case for them, and python has [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in the stdlib.

Comment: You know you don't need linesN variables?

Comment: FYI you don't need to do all that `replace`ing. `line = "hello. \hi ;:world"` then `line.translate(None, '.\;:')` will output `'hello hi world'`

Comment: Why are you doing `lines = infile.read().split(); lines = " ".join(lines)`? You split them just to join them again. You actually want to split them in words, so you can apply @wim's amswer to each one of them.

Answer (score 12):

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) does what you want:

```
>>> 'potato'.strip('o')
'potat'
```

There are also `str.lstrip` and `str.rstrip` if you only want to take off the left or right, respectively.

Comment: apart of being astonished by how short answer can provide such positive feedback - strip can also strip multiple characters like `"potato".strip("op")` returns `"otat"`.

Comment: No, it should return just `"tat"`